# CAGradientLayer with Rounded Top Corners (without using .mask)

Tags: objective-c, screenshot, calayer, quartz-core

I am looking to create a `CAGradientLayer` with rounded corners. I can't use `.cornerRadius` because I would like to round only the top two corners. Also, I cannot use `.mask` because I would like to take a screenshot of it afterwards and `renderInContext` does not support `CALayer` masks.

How can I either:

- A: Create an `CALayer` with a gradient and two rounded corners without using masks

or

- B: Take a screenshot similar to `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`, but respecting the mask.

Comment: I think you should make the layer transparent and set the layer content to an image with top corners rounded.

Comment: I was hoping to do it programatically. This must be possible!

Comment: I want to do the exact same thing, did you figure this out yet?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a programmatic approach to doing this.  It involves creating a rounded layer then drawing a square layer on top of it.  You'll have to do some playing around with the gradient colors and positions to get something that looks good.

**NOTE:** Not sure if this solution will work for you given your requirement about masks

```
+ (void)makeGradientButton:(UIButton *)button {
    // Create a rounded layer
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = button.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
    gradient.cornerRadius = 8.0f;

    // Now create a square layer that draws over the top
    CAGradientLayer *gradient2 = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 9, button.bounds.size.width, button.bounds.size.height-9);
    gradient2.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor], nil];
    gradient2.cornerRadius = 0.0f;

    [gradient setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [button.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    [button.layer insertSublayer:gradient2 atIndex:1];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```